# Как получить размер gif-картинки в ВК?

Tags: php, вконтакте, api

Знаю что в интернете есть полно функций, которые позволяют сделать это, но в ВК есть нюанс, например для скачивания гифки нельзя использовать просто copy() и ссылку, нужно использовать такую функцию:

```
<?php
call($url); // кидает запрос на указанный URL с пользовательским 
// юзерагентом, без этого для ВК не работает.

if (copy($url), './test.gif')) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
   print_r( error_get_last() );
 }

function call($url, $post = null, $_hash = null) {
        if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36');
            if($post) {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
            }
            $out = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return ($out);
        }
  }
?>
```

Собственно вопрос: Как получить размер .gif в ВК с его нюансами?

Comment: Так почему не заюзать API? Метод [`docs.getById`](https://vk.com/dev/docs.getById), вот [демо](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLtPg.png)

Comment: Гифки могут находится в закрытых группах и взять их оттуда можно только  при помощи curl+copy

Comment: Кто вам сказал, что из закрытых групп нельзя получить документы?